# Change POST values in webpages? Riddle help?

Tags: html

I'm kinda new here and I've got a programming/coding related question you guys maybe could help me with. I'm currently playing this game on the net www.darker-future.nl which is sort of a site you got to hack/use IT knowledge to go up levels. I'm kinda stuck at this level which i obviously lack the knowledge of coding for?

Ive got this HTML source code in the page:

```
<form method='POST' action='**************.html'>
<input type=hidden name='40+b+c*d' value='2354'>
<input type=hidden name='a*30-c+d' value='8937'>
<input type=hidden name='a-b-20/d' value='3639'>
<input type=hidden name='a%b+c-10' value='3954'>
<input type=hidden name='a+b*c*d' value='9284'>
<input type=hidden name='a-b/c-d' value='6573'><!-- +0.5 -->
<input type=text name='a*b/c/d'><br>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

I think i got to change the values from the hidden input boxes with the right answers or something. My question: How can I easily fake POST values?

PS. Any tips on maybe things i've forgot to think about in this level please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, get Firebug, open the HTML panel, and edit the value attribute. Simple.

Comment: yes, thanks, exactly what i was looking for. Don't use firefox normally but this could work. (not that it helped me much in the game) im still stuck ;)

Comment: Well if you're using a WebKit-based browser, like Chrome, then you might be able to use the Web Inspector, also. It works pretty much the same way.

Comment: Well I normally just use Safari. But I can easily change the values now. Only problem now is getting the right solution to this riddle. All the previous ones were quite doable. Alot of picture problems which are a bit more my working plane

Comment: Yeah, Safari is WebKit-based. If you have the developer options enabled, you can right click on something and choose "Inspect Element". It'll open it up either in a panel at the bottom of the window or a new window. It works pretty much the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it wants you to change the POST values "in flight" as it were.

Surely you need to find the values of a, b, c and d based on the 6 equations it gives you (simultaneous equations), and put the resulting values into the seventh expression to generate a value.

Then enter this value into the text box and click submit.

Comment: I've got no idea, i think a=40 b=30 c=20 and d=10 or am i thinking too easy? Im gonna recalculate everything again. I probably made an error...

Answer (score 0):

Yes get the firebug extension for Firefox. After it's installed click the little bug icon in the bottom left corner. You can edit the HTML in the firebug window to change the values.

A more long winded solution would be to write some code to generate an HTTP Post request in the correct format.